# Row_Number in table with key where ordering does not make sense

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, window-functions

I am using T-SQL.

I have a temporary table `#t2` with only one column called `internal`.

Values of the column are `n` times a sequence from 1 to 3

i.e. : 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 ...

I want to add this column to another temporary table `#t1` which only has a column of dates called `Date` (assuming that the number of rows of the two table is the same).

If I want to use a join, I need an `on` clause, but I do not have any key that would make sense. Moreover, `cross join` does not work since multiplies the number of columns. Hence, I thought to add a `row_number` to each table and inner join on the newly formed row_number columns.

However, row_number requires an `order by` clause and while `#t1` contains the column `Date` which makes sense to sort on, table `#t2` does not, so the row_number solution does not work either.

I tried to add a column `id` to table `#t2` and add a row_number using a while loop but the column `id` is only populated by `NULL` values.

```
ALTER TABLE #t2
ADD id integer;

declare @iterFlag integer
declare @iteration2 integer
set @iteration2 = (select count(internal) from #t2)
--print @iteration2

set @intFlag = 1
while (@intFlag <= @iteration2)
begin

        INSERT INTO  #t2 (id)
        VALUES (@intFlag)


SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
end;
go
```

If instead of using

```
INSERT INTO  #t2 (id)
VALUES (@intFlag)
```

I use:

```
UPDATE #t2
SET id = @intFlag
```

then I only get the result of `(select count(internal) from #t2)`.

Do you have any solution that would make me stack the two columns one next to each other?

Comment: Please include table DDL, sample data and desired results.

Comment: you can order by a constant/null : ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as concerned your requirement boils down to: assign a number between 1 and 3 to each record in `#t2`. For this, you don't need table `#t1`, you can just use `row_number()`:

```
alter table #t2 add id integer;

with cte as (select id, row_number() over(order by date) - 1 rn from #t2)
update cte set id = 1 + rn % 3;
```

This will assign a value between 1 and 3 to column `id` for each record in `#t2`, ordered by increasing `date`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=44b5f913ebe85886eb5e8f823c03558c)**:

```
create table #t2 (date datetime);

insert into #t2 values 
    ('2020-01-01'), 
    ('2020-01-02'), 
    ('2020-01-03'), 
    ('2020-01-04'), 
    ('2020-01-05'),
    ('2020-01-06'),
    ('2020-01-07');
-- 7 rows affected

alter table #t2 add id integer;

with cte as (select id, row_number() over(order by date) - 1 rn from #t2)
update cte set id = 1 + rn % 3;
-- 7 rows affected

select * from #t2 order by date;
```

```
date                    | id
:---------------------- | -:
2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 |  1
2020-01-02 00:00:00.000 |  2
2020-01-03 00:00:00.000 |  3
2020-01-04 00:00:00.000 |  1
2020-01-05 00:00:00.000 |  2
2020-01-06 00:00:00.000 |  3
2020-01-07 00:00:00.000 |  1
```